# Fourier transformation Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, fft

Please do bear with me if you find my query a little stupid. But I am currently doing a high school research project on how Fourier transformation can be used in recognizing human speech(similar to how Shazam works). But I need to  two different Fast Fourier Transformation algorithms for this project. One of the algorithms I am using would definitely be the Cooley-Tukey FTT algorithm. However, I am unsure of another FTT algorithm I should use. Thus, what would be a good algorithm to use and is there any pseudo code/source code for that particular algorithm? I was only able to find algorithms for Cooley-Tukey thus far.

Thanks!

Comment: The [Wikipedia page on FFTs has a whole list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Other_FFT_algorithms).

Comment: Why would you use two different FFT algorithms? Do you expect different results?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul! I am aware of the existence of the list but my problem was finding any code for the different algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Henrik! Nope I do not expect different results, but instead hope for different speeds. What I am doing requires me to compare at least one independent variable and then draw conclusions from it. As much as I hate it, I do have to do it as it makes part of my IB diploma. More info if you are interested here: http://goo.gl/N9Oj2t

Comment: Are you sure you need 2 FFT algoritms? From your Question I got the impression you need `2 different speech recognition algorithms` booth using FFT. At least that makes much more sense to me ... (if you are not sure ask your supervisor for the project so you do not waste time on silly misunderstanding of assigment) ... If my memory serves well then you want to look for [Cepstral analysis](http://iitg.vlab.co.in/?sub=59&brch=164&sim=615&cnt=1) and [Hidden Markov Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) ... first relevant Google hits I found just now

Comment: If you really need 2 different FFT algorithms then that makes no sense to me because different approaches of the same complexity algorithms are dependent only on the constant time ... the quality of coding style and optimization which can vary a lot and does not tell anything about the algorithms itself but about how you/coder/compiler/platform handle different techniques instead which has no didactical meaning at least to me.

Comment: Hello Spektre, and thanks for the reply. So instead of comparing 2 different FTT algorithms, can I instead compare the FTT with the DTT? Something like what has been done here: http://goo.gl/dxFEGE

Comment: may be but you need to clear this out with your supervisor ... ( also if you want to notify someone in comment you need to add `@` before `nick` so the site recognize this as notify request for example @Spektre )

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need speed (due to some performance constraints), then a DFT (straight matrix multiply) should produce very similar results (differing due to rounding noise) using a very different algorithm.